# Matroids-Discrete Optimization

Tags: discrete-optimization, simplicial-complex, matroids

I happen to stumble across this question where they ask to give an example of an independent system that has two maximal independent sets $X$ and $Y$ such that $|X|\neq |Y|$. How exactly would you formulate such an example?

Comment: *Exactly* two distinct maximal independent sets or *at least* two?

Comment: @Math1000 the question didn't really specify that, but I would assume that  it is two distinct maximal independent sets.

Comment: Do you mean an example of an independent system (instead of set)?

Comment: @sqlman yes! I do mean that, edited the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [independence system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_system) is a collection $C$ of subsets of a finite set $E$ such that if $c \in C$ and $b \subset c$ then $b \in C$. Independence systems are also known as finite [(abstract) simplicial complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex). A simplicial complex whose inclusion-maximal subsets all have the same cardinality is called [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex#Definitions). The question asks for a simplicial complex that is not pure. Here is a minimal example.

Let $E = \{1,2,3\}$ and let $C$ be the set of all subsets of $A = \{1\}$ together with the set of all subsets of $B = \{2,3\}$. So $C = \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{23\}\}$. Then $C$ is an independence system with (inclusion-)maximal subsets $A$ and $B$.

For contrast, a matroid is a simplicial complex whose maximal subsets satisfy the matroid [basis exchange property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Bases_and_circuits). Here's a pure simplicial complex on $E = \{1,2,3,4\}$ that is not a matroid: $C = \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

An example can be constructed by matchings in a graph, where the independent sets are the edges of a matching. Here is a particular case:

[image: Left a graph; next to it two maximal independent systems with different cardinality]
On the left is the graph and next to it, marked in red, the edges of two maximal independent sets with different cardinality. 
If we call the edges from left to right 1,2,3. Then the set of all matchings is $\lbrace \emptyset, 1, 2, 3, 13\rbrace$, where $\lbrace 2\rbrace$ and $\lbrace 1,3\rbrace$ denote the maximal independent sets.

Comment: Indepence systems are also known as (abstract) simplicial complexes. Such a simplicial complex is called pure if all of its maximal faces have the same cardinality. The set of independent sets of a matroid are a pure simplicial complex, but not every pure simplicial complex is a matroid.

Comment: You are right! Deleted the wrong part.